# What is the result of gluing two spheres together?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

What (and why) is the result of gluing two spheres (say $S^2_1$ and $ S^2_2$) together, one of them in opposite direction?

**Edit:** I think that it is not $S^3$!! (maybe the comments are because of my bad explanation). my question is not gluing two balls (because I know sphere has no boundary I used ball to explain it). gluing  two spheres in op. direction. (we have two gluing 1. place one sphere inside of other and identify each point by its corresponding and the result is a sphere, 2. place two spheres touching each other from outside and try to push (gluing) them to each other. (maybe this one is impossible!!!)

My question is about (2) in the above Edit. e.g. consider two circles in plan, touching each other from outside. Then try to identify each point with its corresponding point near touching point such that this two loops remain in plan.

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect ? Its genus ? Fundamental group ? Another thing ? Sphere of which dimension ?

Comment: maybe its known name if has. or it is homeomorph to? any thing that I can recognize it.

Comment: Spheres don't have a boundary, so what do you mean by "glue them along their boundary"? Also, what do you mean by the *direction* of a sphere?

Comment: Your space is just $S^3$, the $3$-sphere. In particular, you can't embed it in $\mathbb R^3$, so it's hard to visualize

Answer (score 5):

When you glue two copies of $B^n$ along their boundary spheres $\partial B^n=S^{n-1}$ you obtain $S^n$. Glue two arcs along their boundaries ($S^0$ is just two dots) and you obtain the circle. Glue two disks along their circle boundaries ($S^1$!) and you obtain $S^2$. As one user commented, the same holds with $B^3$'s glued along their $S^2$'s only it is difficult to visualize the space totally.

But, analogy can go a long way. One of my favorite ways to visualize $S^3$ is as two disjoint balls, but we keep track of the gluing. So a person living in this space swims from one ball to the other passing through the boundary spheres.